# Fragments Behave Weirdly When Using addToBackStack()

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

An SSCCE for this issue is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/win93/FragmentTest).

For future readers, the original example is on a [branch of the same project](https://github.com/win93/FragmentTest/tree/original), and the fix is available [in this diff](https://github.com/win93/FragmentTest/commit/e5f4921d9560559b3785c3c139e7721ec0dd4ea8).

This SSCCE has a ListView and a row of buttons. The buttons are supposed to change the data in the ListView, and the listView rows (when clicked) are supposed to open a new fragment and advance the backstack while staying in the same activity.

If do the following things, it produces the following result:

1. Open the app.
2. Tap the ListView. - `FragmentTransaction.replace(...)` with `addToBackStack(true)`
3. Tap any of the buttons. - `FragmentTransaction.replace(...)` with `addToBackStack(false)`
4. Tap the back button.

Result:

[image: Overlapping Fragments]

Both fragments become visible, but I only want the first loaded fragment (`ListTwoFragment` in code) to display. Is this how fragments are supposed to work? If so, how can I get the desired effect?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ListTwoFragment.Callbacks,
    ListThreeFragment.Callbacks {
    public static final String KEY_ARGS = "args";

    private String curUri = "";
    private String curArgs = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        selectContent(false);
    }

    private void selectContent(boolean addToBackStack) {
        Fragment fragment;

        if (curUri.isEmpty()) {
            // Use default fragment
            fragment = new ListTwoFragment();
            curUri = ListTwoFragment.class.getName();
        }
        else {
            try {
                Class<Fragment> fragmentClass = (Class<Fragment>) Class.forName(curUri);
                fragment = fragmentClass.newInstance();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { // ClassNotFound, IllegalAccess, etc.
                return;
            }
        }

        // Configure fragment
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(KEY_ARGS, curArgs);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        attachFragment(fragment, addToBackStack, curUri + ";" + curArgs, R.id.fragment_container);
    }

    protected void attachFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack, String tag, int replaceId) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(replaceId, fragment, tag);
        if (addToBackStack) transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTwoButtonClick(String title) {
        curUri = ListTwoFragment.class.getName();
        curArgs = title;
        selectContent(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTwoListClick() {
        curUri = ListThreeFragment.class.getName();
        curArgs = "";
        selectContent(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onThreeButtonClick(String title) {
        curUri = ListThreeFragment.class.getName();
        curArgs = title;
        selectContent(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm working with Fragments to, and the way I'm doing it:
to go forward (add to stack), and backwords (remove from stack) are two different functions

to Add to Stack and change Fragment:

```
public void changeFragmentAddToStack(Fragment myNewFragment) {
        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.add(R.id.main_fragment, myNewFragment);
        t.addToBackStack(null);
        t.commit();
    }
```

To go back Stack:

```
        public void goBackStackMain() {
    FragmentManager man = getSupportFragmentManager();

                if(man.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){ 
                    man.popBackStack(man.getBackStackEntryAt(0).getName(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }
}
```

And if you want to do both: To go back stack and change fragment:

```
    public void goBackStackAndReplaceFragment(Fragment myNewFragment) {
FragmentManager man = getSupportFragmentManager();
            if(man.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){ 
                int n = man.getBackStackEntryCount();
                man.popBackStack(man.getBackStackEntryAt(n-1).getName(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }

        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.replace(R.id.main_fragment, myNewFragment);
        t.commit();
    }
```

I hope to help you !

Comment: If Just updated the answer I forgot a little thing that "man" its FragmentManager man = getSupportFragmentManager();

Comment: the third one did :D (with some slight modifications)

Comment: i will copy what i do in my code and it runs perfect:   

i have three thing Fragment - MyApplication class - MainActivity 

in activity i have those functions 

from fragment i call to MyApp class

MyApp.goMainBackStack(getActivity());
public void goMainBackStack(Activity a) {
  MainActivity fca = (MainActivity)a;
  fca.goBackStackMain();
 }

in Main
 public void goBackStackMain() {
 
   man.popBackStack(man.getBackStackEntryAt(0).getName(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
  
 }

and i add to stack the same way as the answer

Comment: If you want to see how i am using your code, see the GitHub link.