# Switching fragments in Sliding Menu?

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

There's a time come when someone include some codes without explaining. Well, this time it's this case because the codes aren't hard at all.
I'm trying to switch fragments in sliding drawer.
Codes:

```
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

**Here's DrawerItemClickListener Class:**

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment frag = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Algeria);
        break;
    case 1:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Bahrain);

        break;
    case 2:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Comoros);
        break;
    case 3:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Djibouti);
        break;
    case 4:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Egypt);
        break;
    case 5:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Iraq);
        break;
    case 6:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Jordan);
        break;
    case 7:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Kuwait);
        break;
    case 8:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Lebanon);
        break;
    case 9:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Libya);
        break;
    case 10:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Mauritania);
        break;
    case 11:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Morocco);
        break;
    case 12:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Oman);
        break;
    case 13:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Pelastine);
        break;
    case 14:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Qatar);
        break;
    case 15:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Saudi_Arabia);
        break;
    case 16:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Somalia);
        break;
    case 17:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Sudan);
        break;
    case 18:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Syria);
        break;
    case 19:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Tunisia);
        break;
    case 20:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Emirates);
        break;
    case 21:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Yemen);
        break;
    }
    ft.commit();

}
```

**BUT IT DOESN'T WORK**
No bugs at all, just nothing show at the screen! i know the fragment work 100% but it doesn't show on the screen. Well WHY!?
Thanks. :)

**UPDATE FUL CODES**:

```
public class Drawer extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
    String[] title;
    String[] subtitle;
    int[] icon;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    public static String prefName = "SecretFile";
    Fragment Algeria = new Fragment1();
    Fragment Bahrain = new Fragment2();
    Fragment Comoros = new Fragment3();
    Fragment Djibouti = new Fragment4();
    Fragment Egypt = new Fragment5();
    Fragment Iraq = new Fragment6();
    Fragment Jordan = new Jordan();
    Fragment Kuwait = new Fragment8();
    Fragment Lebanon = new Lebanon();
    Fragment Libya = new Fragment10();
    Fragment Mauritania = new Fragment11();
    Fragment Morocco = new Fragment12();
    Fragment Oman = new Fragment13();
    Fragment Pelastine = new Fragment14();
    Fragment Qatar = new Qatar();
    Fragment Saudi_Arabia = new Fragment16();
    Fragment Somalia = new Fragment17();
    Fragment Sudan = new Fragment18();
    Fragment Syria = new Fragment19();
    Fragment Tunisia = new Fragment20();
    Fragment Emirates = new Fragment21();
    Fragment Yemen = new Fragment22();
    ConnectivityManager connMgr;
    NetworkInfo networkInfo;
    ListView mDrawerList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SlidingMenu sm = new SlidingMenu(this);
        title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_array);
        icon = new int[] { R.drawable.algeria, R.drawable.bahrain,
                R.drawable.comoros, R.drawable.djibouti, R.drawable.egypt,
                R.drawable.iraq, R.drawable.jordan, R.drawable.kuwait,
                R.drawable.lebanon, R.drawable.libya, R.drawable.mauritania,
                R.drawable.morocco, R.drawable.oman, R.drawable.pelastine,
                R.drawable.qatar, R.drawable.saudiarabia, R.drawable.somalia,
                R.drawable.sudan, R.drawable.syria, R.drawable.tunisia,
                R.drawable.emirates, R.drawable.yemen, };
        sm.setMenu(R.layout.drawer_main);
        sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
        sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        sm.setFadeDegree(0.7f);
        sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        sm.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);
        sm.setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(this, title, icon);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    }

    private int seethefirstactivity() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int fragmento;
        connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        fragmento = prefs.getInt("country", 1);
        if (fragmento == 0) {
            Algeria = new Fragment1();

        } else if (fragmento == 1) {
            Bahrain = new Fragment2();

        } else if (fragmento == 2) {
            Comoros = new Fragment3();

        } else if (fragmento == 3) {
            Djibouti = new Fragment4();

        } else if (fragmento == 4) {
            Egypt = new Fragment5();

        } else if (fragmento == 5) {
            Iraq = new Fragment6();

        } else if (fragmento == 6) {
            Jordan = new Jordan();

        } else if (fragmento == 7) {
            Kuwait = new Fragment8();

        } else if (fragmento == 8) {

            Lebanon = new Lebanon();

        } else if (fragmento == 9) {
            Libya = new Fragment10();

        } else if (fragmento == 10) {
            Mauritania = new Fragment11();

        } else if (fragmento == 11) {
            Morocco = new Fragment12();

        } else if (fragmento == 12) {
            Oman = new Fragment13();

        } else if (fragmento == 13) {
            Pelastine = new Fragment14();

        } else if (fragmento == 14) {
            Qatar = new Qatar();

        } else if (fragmento == 15) {
            Saudi_Arabia = new Fragment16();

        } else if (fragmento == 16) {
            Somalia = new Fragment17();

        } else if (fragmento == 17) {
            Sudan = new Fragment18();

        } else if (fragmento == 18) {
            Syria = new Fragment19();

        } else if (fragmento == 19) {
            Tunisia = new Fragment20();

        } else if (fragmento == 20) {
            Emirates = new Fragment21();

        } else if (fragmento == 21) {
            Yemen = new Fragment22();

        }
        return fragmento;
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment frag = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Algeria);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Bahrain);

            break;
        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Comoros);
            break;
        case 3:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Djibouti);
            break;
        case 4:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Egypt);
            break;
        case 5:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Iraq);
            break;
        case 6:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Jordan);
            break;
        case 7:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Kuwait);
            break;
        case 8:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Lebanon);
            break;
        case 9:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Libya);
            break;
        case 10:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Mauritania);
            break;
        case 11:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Morocco);
            break;
        case 12:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Oman);
            break;
        case 13:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Pelastine);
            break;
        case 14:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Qatar);
            break;
        case 15:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Saudi_Arabia);
            break;
        case 16:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Somalia);
            break;
        case 17:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Sudan);
            break;
        case 18:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Syria);
            break;
        case 19:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Tunisia);
            break;
        case 20:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Emirates);
            break;
        case 21:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Yemen);
            break;
        }
        ft.commit();

    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe this is inconsequential, but you never use `frag`. Are all those country names fragments? Have they been initialized?

Comment: updated. All the application was working well before i change from navigation drawer to sliding menu...

Comment: oh lord this is baaad

Comment: bad?? why this is bad?

Comment: Look how many Fragments you new up in onCreate, look at the amount of code duplication in that if statement. Then you duplicate the if statement again as a switch.

Comment: Duplication is my game ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i think you haven't used MyApplication class much.. no problem i will show you:

MyApplication class we could say it's a "common", accessible class used to store/restore data with methods at any time in you App:

So let's start:

in your Manifest:

```
<application

        android:name=".MyApplication"

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="myPackageName"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

if you see in the code there is " **android:name=".MyApplication"** " thats your MyApplication class name you will create in your project.

Now we just create a simple class and extends to " Application "

```
package youPackageName;

public class MyApplication extends Application {


/**
*  IN HERE WILL BE ALL YOUR VARIABLES AND METHODS
*/
}
```

so how to use it?
easy...

we will say that you whant to save a simple string ok? with  methods to get and set that string

```
    package youPackageName;

    public class MyApplication extends Application {

    String mString = "";

// To set my string 
public void setMyString(String s){
this.mString = s;
}
// get string 
public String getMyString(){
return this.mString;
}

// one you seted ones that string it will be abailable at any moment while your app is not destroyed

    }
```

From your activity we will call that method in that app class how?

```
MyApplication MyApp;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MyApp = ((MyApplication)getApplicationContext());


//SET
MyApp.setMyString("HELLO");

//GET
String a = MyApp.getMyString();

}
```

**NOW ! FRAGMENTS!**

My layout is very simple:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in your MainActivity:

```
                           // myNewFragment: FRAG TO BE REPLACE
public void changeFragment(Fragment myNewFragment) {
        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.replace(R.id.main_frag, myNewFragment);
        t.commit();
}
```

in your MyApplication class we just created before

```
public void switchFragmentNormal(Activity a, Fragment newContent) {
        MainActivity fca = (MainActivity)a;
        fca.changeFragment(newContent);
}
```

And NOW Finally from any fragment or SlideMenu

Just do this;

```
MyApplication MyApp;
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

MyApp = (MyApplication)getActivity().getApplicationContext();

MyApp.switchFragmentNormal(getActivity(), new FragmentVote());
}
```

And thats it, now you have a class that's available at any time where you can store variables methods etc.

:-)

Comment: awesome i will try that and tell you the result.

Comment: sure, any doubts tell me !

Comment: can you show me how can i do it in my codes??? and how can i launch a default fragment dependant on my sharedpreferences?

Comment: What i would do is create all those new statements in MyApp->Frag1 f1 = new Frag1();|Frag2 f2 = new Frag2();| function to switch fragment in Main (Drawer i think)|get that indicator (int) saying which country is the one to show, and call method to change|LIKE THIS: switch(POS){case 0:switch(MyApp.f1); case 1:switch(MyApp.f2);..} delete commit from switch put in in method, best in methods all capsulated in one place faster to update after...make sure that you set content inflate fragments1,2,3etc.properly...And Then from your other frag call throw MyApp that switch()method as I explained before

Comment: just put them in different functions so you can call them any time

Comment: can you contact me in private?

Comment: can you send private messages in stackoverflow?

Comment: Nice ! what was the issue ??

Answer (score 0):

When I work with fragments I doit this way:

In the **MainActivity:**

```
public void changeFragment(int frag, Fragment myNewFragment) {
        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.replace(frag, myNewFragment);
        //t.addToBackStack(null);
        t.commit();
}
```

And the in my **MyApplication class** y have small functions so I can call them any time:

```
public void switchFragmentNormal(Activity a, Fragment newContent) {
        MainActivity fca = (MainActivity)a;
        fca.changeFragment(R.id.main_fragment, newContent);
}
```

So this way, from any fragment or slide menu i do a small call and I will change it easily:
and I make a "new somthing()" just when I need to:

```
FragmentVote fvote = new FragmentVote();
MyApp.switchFragmentNormal(getActivity(), fvote);
```

to change fragment and close the slidemenu "SlidingMenu- made by : jfeinstein10" do it this way:

```
SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT); 
...
   public void changeFragmentFromList(int frag, Fragment myNewFragment) {
            sm.toggle();    // this closes the slidemenu
            FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            t.replace(frag, myNewFragment);
            t.commit();
    }
```

and to call it: **MyApplication class**

```
public void switchFragmentNormalList(Activity a, Fragment newContent) {
        MainActivity fca = (MainActivity)a;
        fca.changeFragmentFromList(R.id.main_fragment, newContent);
}
```

Then: and I make a "new somthing()" just when I need to:

```
FragmentVote fvote = new FragmentVote();
MyApp.switchFragmentNormalList(getActivity(), fvote);
```

Then sometimes i want to add to stack my fragment so i can do other stuff etc.

check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17978786/2625912

Hope help you !

Comment: so how can i implement it in my application? i spend half an hour without any result..